# What are the halachot when finding a Sefer Torah on the floor?

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah

Recently, 6 Torah Scrolls that were stolen from the Tzemach Tzedek shul in Yerushalaim were [found on the floor of a cave](http://www.crownheights.info/index.php?itemid=43905).

I am curious what the halachic differences are (if any) between finding a Sefer Torah on the floor as opposed to seeing it fall.

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav ([Orach Chaim 44:2)](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/5/44/2) quotes the Magen Avraham ([Orach Chaim 44:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&pgnum=195)) who says that the custom is to fast if a Sefer Torah falls, even if the Sefer Torah is in its cover. [The Magen Avraham bases this on the [Mishpitei Shmuel, 12](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1321&pgnum=12)]

[This link](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/10/02/sefer-torah-fell/) differentiates between dropping and witnessing the fall, so perhaps there are differences if one didn't even see get on the floor, but I didn't look up the sources brought on that page.

Comment: I haven't read it yet, but here is R' Moshe's Teshuvah, quoted in the article: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&pgnum=294

Comment: Here's a link to the Tzitz Eliezer mentioned in the article: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14504&pgnum=28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Menachem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/603/menachem) linked to the *Tzitz Eliezer*, volume 5, responsum 1. Therein, [chapter 5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14504&pgnum=42) discusses, among other things, our question. He writes (in my own very loose translation):

> As was explained in the previous chapter, there's seemingly no basis for a requirement to fast imposed on those who saw a *sefer Tora* fall.… Nonetheless, many great *pos'kim* have required that not only those who saw the *sefer* fast but also others who pray in that synagogue and live there who were not even present. Let us examine the basis for this and what other *pos'kim* hold.
>
> *Ikare Dinim* (*OC* 2:15, citing *S'de Haaretz* 3:31) has:
>
> > If he didn't drop it and didn't see it fall, but saw it on the ground, there's not even a custom to fast; one who does so should be blessed.
>
> … *Olas Yitzchak* 67, after explaining the lack of basis for fasting altogether… adds at the end that
>
> > Jews are holy and fast even if they saw the *sefer* fall from another. I'll even add a further stringency: in our case, where they didn't even see it fall but saw it lying on the ground, they should fast one day of [*B'hab*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%27anit)…
>
> and the like is in *Chazon Nachum* 86 who requires a fast of someone who came across a *sefer Tora* lying in disgrace on the floor, as well as the sexton and *gabaim*.
>
> However, *Yad El'azar* 126 took for granted that those who come across a *sefer Tora* lying on the floor need not fast, since they did not see the fall. He did require that they 'redeem' their fast with some nominal charity for the poor; and he did require a fast of the sexton or officer who could have set the *sefer* in place and closed the cabinet properly.
>
> …
>
> What we get out of all this is that there's a great basis for not requiring any fast at all, not even as a mere stringency, of those who did not see the fall, even if they saw the *sefer Tora* on the ground. Also, even those who wrote that those stringent on themselves should be blessed wrote that only of those who saw the *sefer* on the ground in disgrace.