# Sefer Torah in reshus harabim

Tags: shabbat, sefer-torah, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

If one finds a Torah on the floor in a reshus harabim on shabbas what should one do? It is a big  bizoyn to leave  it on the floor but to pick it up and carry it is problematic.

Question inspired by: [What are the halachot when finding a Sefer Torah on the floor?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/what-are-the-halachot-when-finding-a-sefer-torah-on-the-floor)

Comment: Presumably you mean that it's smack in the middle of the road, and there are more than 4 amos to the side. Otherwise you could just pick it up and hold it.

Comment: You're supposed to wait there with it until after shabbat. If it is dangerous, you wear the scroll as a cloak and walk away. Source coming soon...

Comment: Also, there are _way_ bigger bizayons than leaving it on the floor!

Comment: edited it, I meant it is a big bizyon,source would be great,thanks

Comment: @sam Hmmm... See Shulchan Aruch OC 301:43. He doesn't mention specifically the floor issue, although it's kind of implied that even if there is no table around you just sit around and wait like an honor guard.

Comment: I'm just thinking again, what is the problem with picking it up, provided you don't walk around?

Answer (score 1):

Pick it up. Stay there for the rest of shabbos. If Its to hard/dangerous to stay there the whole shabbos 1) switch with other people 2) carry it with another person (melacha that can be done by one person, if done by two - patur perek 1 of shabbos) 3) carry it less than 4 amos at a time

Comment: How do you know this? 2 and 3 are still rabbinicly prohibited in general. Do have reason to think those prohibitions wouldn't apply in this case?

Comment: there is no problem to pick something up in reshus harabim, the melacha is hotzaah-carrying a)4 amos in reshus horabim/carmelis b) from reshus horabim to reshus hayachid or vice versa, This is a mishna in the first perek of shabbos. Two people doing one melach Perek 10:5. Also see perek 11

Comment: I know picking up is not a problem. I'm asking how you know this is the recommended procedure, and how you know that 2 and 3 are even permitted at all in this case

Comment: Once you pick it up you cant put it back down. (that would be actively being mevaze the sefer). If its to dangerous i.e. pikuach nefesh thats when the melachos derabanan become mutar through a shiunui.

Comment: Pikuach nefesh malochois deorisa are permitted without a shinui, this spesific case is brought in the Shulchan aruch 301.43 (and if it is pikuach nefesh you should leave it there not carry it) please bring a source that shows that I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

[Shulchan aruch harav 301.54](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/301a/54.htm)
See footnotes for sources

> וכן אם מצא ספר תורה בשדה בימי הגזירה שגזרו שלא ללומדו מכסהו במקומו והולך לו ואם אינו זמן הגזירה צריך לישב ולשמרו עד שתחשך ואז יביאנו לביתו ואם היו הגשמים יורדים שמתקלקל הספר אם יהיה כאן עד הלילה יתעטף בהספר כעין מלבוש וחוזר ומכסה עליו בבגדיו ומביאו לביתו מיד שאף שאינו דרך מלבוש גמור התירו לו מפני כבוד התורה

My approximate translation

> and so if you found a sefee torah in the field in the time of a decree (that they decreed that it is forbidden to learn it) you should cover it where it is and go.
>   If it is not in the time of the decree you need to sit and guard it until it gets dark (after shabos), and then bring it home.
>   If rain is coming down which will ruin the safer if it stays hear until the evening, wrap the sefer as a cloak and but your clothes over it and bring it home right away even though it is not the way of clothing [might be considered rabbinical carrying], they permitted it for the respect of the Torah