# Why is there a minhag to stand for the public reading of the 10 Commandments throughout the year?

Tags: torah-reading, aseres-hadibros

Yesterday, my rav read from [Otzar Dinim U'minhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37057&st=&pgnum=342), where he explains the the only time people stand for the reading of the 10 Commandments is when it is read during the Shabbat that we read *parshat Yitro*.

I have seen in every Orthodox Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard shul, as well as Conservative shuls that people stand whenever the 10 Commandments are read - whether it's Yitro, Va'etchanan or during Shavuot.

What's the purpose of standing for the 10 Commandments at all times? Doesn't it relay a message, in a sense, that the 10 Commandments are more "important" than other parts of the Torah? (I'll ask a separate question regarding *Shira* as there's a minhag to stand for that, too.) What would make this more worthy of standing than anything else? (E.g., why not stand for the 13 *middot* when they are read in shul (as they are numerous times during the year). There is a minhag to stand when reciting these as part of *Selichot*.)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55534/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Agree that it is a dupe of your suggestion. I don't understand your reference in your 1st comment.

Comment: The last paragraph of the joke answer.