# What direction did the Great Sanhedrin face?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, sanhedrin

[image]

In the standard scheme of the Temple and the Great Sanhedrin, taking the fact that they sat in an arc, what direction did they face - South (Altar), East (Ezrat Nashim), West(K"K) or North (wall)?

---

I've found this drawing of the Temple of the Institute of the Temple (מכון המקדש), seemingly depicting the Sanhedrin facing west (K"K):

[image]

Does anybody know the source of this detail? It also puts the Sanhedrin into the Azara, which is impossible as they are not Kohanim - could it be a mistake?

Comment: Weren't they sitting outside the Azara (obviously, since only kings can) but the witnesses were in the Azara? That would mean they faced west.

Comment: Non kohanim can be in the azara. That's how they brought Korbanot

Comment: I believe it is a mistake, as I explained in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106999/19563).