# Fasting when Navi on Klaf falls on the floor

Tags: halacha, tanach, navi-prophets, sefer-torah

As is known, if a Sefer Torah falls on the floor (even if it's covered) there is a halacha that one must fast. ([See this question and answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/what-are-the-halachot-when-finding-a-sefer-torah-on-the-floor) for many sources on this topic.) What about in a case when Navi or Kesuvim that was written on klaf fell on the floor (either when it was covered or not covered it -- if there is any difference in regards to Navi/Kesuvim)?

Comment: Can also ask the same question about a _k'laf_ of, say, _B'reshis_.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the linked question, the source of the minhag is from Mishpetei Shemuel 12. He brings a saying of the people (quoted in Shulchan Aruch OC 288:5) that one must fast if he sees a Torah burnt in his sleep. He extends this rule to fasting when a Torah is dropped by his own logic, and then extends it again to tefillin being dropped based on a gemara (Moed Kattan 26a) which says that if a Torah or tefillin is forcefully burnt one must rend one's clothes. As the Rosh (Moed Katan 3:64, ruled in Shulchan Aruch YD 340:37) extends the requirement of clothes-rending to even "one parsha from Nevi'im or Ketuvim", it would seem that the Mishpetei Shemuel's logic follows here as well.

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2012/11/11/navi-fell-to-the-ground/

Comment: @Ploni an argument from silence by "Admin". I've seen worse.