# How do we understand the vessel with a חלל טפח protecting tefillin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin

The [Oruch HaShulchan O Ch 43 (13)](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%92) writes that one can put ones tefillin on the floor if they are in a bag which has a חלל טפח.  He refers to מגן אברהם סעיף קטן י"ג וסעיף קטן י"ד .

> צריך דווקא כלי שיהיה בו חלל טפח, דאז חשיב אוהל להפסיק בינם להקרקע
>
> You need specifically a vessel that has a  חלל טפח since then it is
>   considered an  אוהל to interpose between the tefilin and the ground.

How do we understand the vessel with  a  חלל טפח?

Is it sufficient that the vessel has a space of a tefach or must it have a space of a tefach in addition to the space taken up by the tefillin?

related: [Placing Tefillin on the floor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67880/placing-tefillin-on-the-floor)

Comment: As a bag with great rollers or a bicompartimental bag or a table, a bed with foots

Comment: @kouty How do you know that is right?

Comment: @kouty The Rashi you quote in the related case reads, “דחללו טפח דחשיב הכלי אהל להפסיק בינם לקרקע "
I would translate that as “the space of a tefach causes the vessel to be considered as an ohel to intervene between them and the floor”.  It “causes the vessel to be considered as an ohel” rather than the vessel actually is an ohel.

Comment: The Magen Avraham http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x410 never says "חלל טפח". He just says "טפח". I don't know what Rashi he refers to.

Comment: @DoubleAA : The Rashi is on the [Gemoro Brochos 23a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=23&format=text) and Rashi says: עושה להם כיס טפח. דחללו טפח דחשיב הכלי אהל להפסיק בינם לקרקע:

Comment: @Avrohom Yitzchok sorry but I don't understand.  If you   mean that my English translation of Rashi is wrong,  it is because I don't knw English.  You can improve and edit

Comment: The חילוק רשויות is learned from ohel who chotsets from tum'at met